# Upgrade Hbase to new version

Tags: hbase

I'm using Hbase 1.0.1 and Hadoop 2.6, the cluster has 20 servers with 100TB data. Right I wanna upgrade my Hbase to version 1.2. Are the data format compatible between the two versions? Or any risks please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are compatible and you should be fine with the upgrade. Recently I did the upgrade with out any issues.

You can test the same on sandbox, if you are really concern.

Comment: Are they using the same Hfile format version please?

Comment: According to https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/book.html#hbase.versioning HBase with the same major version number have compatible file formats, @Jack.